# Are there any "responsive" book publishing libraries like Turnjs?

Tags: turnjs

I'm aware of [Turnjs](http://turnjs.com) V4 but that library is outdated, no longer maintained and isn't responsive by default. Notably, turnjs is also not [available under any suitable license](https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/554) for use in free & open source or commercial software.

Have seen many other jQuery plugins but none of 'em come close to performance of turnjs. So I wonder if there are any alternatives for the said library with similar performance?

I ask because if there isn't, I may have to jump in and write one myself.

Comment: * I'm not an attorney, but from the comments in the link you provided and what [opensource.org](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause) says about the licence, you should be free to use it for commercial use, you just can't redistribute it and you have to leave the copyright notification in.  That said - I'd love to see another project that is maintained, so if you create one let some people know.

Comment: I did start one that I'm working on and off, mostly on weekends: https://github.com/marvindanig/flippy.JS